# Delete value with HBase-Hive integration

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, delete-row

I am using HBase-Hive integration to read and write HBase with Hive, following [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration).

Basically, I create a table in Hive with `HBaseStorageHandler` like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase.test (
  col1 string,
  col2 map<string, double>
)
STORED BY
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'hbase.columns.mapping'=':key, cf:',
  'hbase.table.name'='test')
```

It's working perfectly reading and writing. But now I want to clear some bad data by value. This value is in both row key and column cell, i.e. col1, and key of col2.

I did not find anything related to data deletion in the [document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration). Hopefully, someone has similar experience can answer my question here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The nearest use case for your delete is overwrite. You can find it in the documentation you provided.

In general, delete is not easily achieved in big data area. In HBase they are achieved using tombstones and compactions. 
In Hive, its only available from 0.14 version. And that too for tables that support ACID. Again ACID is supported from 0.13.

As you can see, the work on deletion for bid data sets is only picking recently. 
You need to plan better options like insert overwrite to handle erasing bad data.

Since you are not using each framework individually - like hbase or hive as standalone, you would not be getting full features for either of them. An integration is only good if you have heavy SQL view and HBase at the back end.

Again, why HBase was chosen at the back end, might have its own requirements. Hope this helps in designing better solutions

Comment: Overwrite will not delete existing data in hbase but only update. Since it's not very large data volume deletion, my final solution is to follow [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_delete_data.htm)

Comment: Just want to confirm two things  - The overwrite as I mentioned was the nearest and not complete. Also I was assuming that you want to delete the data from hive and that should reflect in HBase. the link provided is for hbase deletion. I hope your requirement is served if you delete from HBase. Happy Coding.